# c# webservice - validate params and throw exception/error via soap

Tags: c#, web-services, validation

What is the best way to validate WebMethod params .
I guess this not best practice:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(String sayHi)
        {
            if (sayHi.Equals(""))
            {
                throw new Exception("User not provided");
            }
            return "String OK";
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

You should use `string` not `String`.

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(string sayHi)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sayHi)                
       throw new ArgumentException("User not provided");

   return "String OK";
}
```

Comment: Check out using the SoapException type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480514.aspx